# Pulling my hair out on orderby issue

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

Here's my code:

```
var students = db.Students.Where(p => p.active == true).OrderBy(z => z.lastname)

return View(students)
```

In the view, I iterate through the model of Students.  The first row is "fullname".  But this is always displaying by alpha of the first name, not the last.  What is causing this?

Comment: post your view code as well, it may help!

Comment: Is this some grid component with built-in sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Gert, you're good.  I slept on it, then had a Eureka moment the following morning.  Yes, the damn recordset is pulled into jquery datatables.  That was sorting on the fullname.  Can't believe I lost an hour on this last night.